# How to retrieve the text displayed in the comobobox (winform) binded with anonymous list?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, combobox, anonymous-types

In my .net 3.5 win-form app, i am binding a combo box with these statements.

```
using (var db = new NewspaperDataContext())
            {
                var list = from p in db.Customers
                           orderby p.Name ascending
                           select new
                                      {
                                          p.Id,
                                          p.Name
                                      };
                 cboCustReport.DataSource= list;
               cboCustReport.DisplayMember = "Name";
                cboCustReport.ValueMember = "Id";
                cboCustReport.SelectedIndex = -1;
            }
```

But while retrieving the selected text from the combo box, i am ""(empty), If I use SelectedItem property, then I have {Id= 3 , Name = Amit Ranjan }. When I added a watch and tried to build the expression, It gave me something like this:

```
((<>f__AnonymousType2<int,string>)(cboCustReport.SelectedItem)).Name;
```

Please help me, what should I use to get the value of property name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to eagerly execute the query by calling `.ToList()` at the end:

```
var list = (from p in db.Customers
            orderby p.Name ascending
            select new
            {
                p.Id,
                p.Name
            }).ToList();
```